# Connection error on MariaDB using pymysql

Tags: python, mariadb, pymysql

I try to use the Python library **PyMySQL 0.9.3** on a **Debian 10.3** server using **Python 3.7.3** to connect to a local MariaDB 10.4.12 server.

```
~# pip3 show PyMySQL
Name: PyMySQL
Version: 0.9.3
Summary: Pure Python MySQL Driver
...
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages

~# python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

For test purpose, I created a database **db1** and a user **user1** on my MariaDB 10.4 server:

```
CREATE DATABASE db1 DEFAULT CHARSET utf8mb4;
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO user1@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
```

I confirm that I can connect to db1 with the credentials above:

```
~# mysql -NB -hlocalhost -uuser1 -p1234 db1 -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version'"
version 10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~buster-log
```

Now, let's create a Python script (test.py):

```
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user1',
                             password='1234',
                             db='db1',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

=> Running this script leads to an error:

```
~# python3 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 598, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 975, in _get_server_information
    packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 671, in _read_packet
    % (packet_number, self._next_seq_id))
pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 0
```

What's wrong with my setup? Did I missed some library or so? Or is PyMySQL incompatible with MariaDB 10.4?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this issue yet?

Comment: Did you found a solution in the mean time?